# java.lang.ArrayStoreException

Tags: java, exception, arraylist

As I am testing with Junit, I can't seem to get this test to run. It only says error and "java.lang.ArrayStoreException" on the Failure trace. It would be a great help if someone could solve my issue. `LinkedInUser` is a object I made, the `getConnections` method returns an `List<LinkedInUser>` data type.

```
@Test
public void testSort() throws LinkedInException {//Test sorting
    LinkedInUser user0 = new LinkedInUser("Han", null);
    LinkedInUser user1 = new LinkedInUser("LUKE", null);
    LinkedInUser user2 = new LinkedInUser("leia", null);

    user0.addConnection(user1);//Han gets 2 connections
    user0.addConnection(user2);

    List<LinkedInUser> friends = user0.getConnections();//Transfer to array
    Collections.sort(friends);//Sort

    Assert.assertEquals(user2, friends.get(0));//Compare
    Assert.assertEquals(user1, friends.get(1));
    }
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to provide the stack trace of the error. It would also be beneficial to provide a [mre] demonstrating the problem.

Comment: Can you please also post the following:

 1. The ```LinkedInUser``` and ```LinkedInException``` classes
 2. The stack trace

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are saving LinkedInUser in unmatched type array.

**ArrayStoreException in Java**

```
ArrayStoreException in Java occurs whenever an attempt is made to store the wrong type of object into an array of objects. The ArrayStoreException is a class which extends RuntimeException, which means that it is an exception thrown at the runtime.
```

public class ArrayStoreException extends RuntimeException

```
Thrown to indicate that an attempt has been made to store the wrong type of object into an array of objects. For example, the following code generates an ArrayStoreException:
     Object x[] = new String[3];
     x[0] = new Integer(0);
```